# Waiting for a page to load before display all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

Hi All I have a countdown timer that appears accross multiple pages using JQuery, I am using local storage:

```
var countdowntimervalue = 100;                            // Some variable
localStorage.setItem('timer_value', countdowntimervalue); // <-- Set the value
```

however when moving between pages and getting the value from local storage - if a user moves between the pages quick enough the counter will not count down, - is there a way to wait until the counter is loaded before displaying the page, heres the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var count = localStorage.getItem('count') || 60
                    countdown = setInterval(function() {
                        localStorage.setItem('count'), count);
                        $("span.countdown").html(minutes + ":" + seconds + " Remaining");

                        if (count == 0) {
                            clearInterval(countdown);
                            localStorage.removeItem('count');
                        }
                        count--;
                    }, 1000);
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: I'd recommend storing the start time instead, and then calculating time elapsed.  What you're doing with an interval *will* have the problem you are facing.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Answer (score 0):

It started as a comment, but here's the code...

```
$(function() {
    var startTime = localStorage.getItem("startTime");
    if (startTime == null) {
        startTime = new Date().getTime();
        localStorage.setItem("startTime", startTime);
    }
    var countdown = setInterval(function() {
        var elapsed = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - startTime) / 1000);
        var remaining = 60 - elapsed;
        $("span.countdown").html(remaining + " seconds Remaining");
        if (remaining == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdown);
            localStorage.removeItem("startTime");
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Store the start time and then calculate the time elapsed since then.  If you want to get really messy then you can also calculate the time between pages so that you get 60 seconds of "on page" time, rather than 60 seconds that includes page transitions.

Either way, that will solve your immediate issue of the timer not going down.